# A way to have table-rows with height 0 and overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I know it should not be possible, but maybe there's some new quirk... Take a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/1hnxzyux/4/

So I'm using `display:table, table-cell and table-row`.

I was previously able to get a row to zero height if it doesn't contain anything or if it contains a `display:none` element, but on the fiddle you can see I've tried to hide the first row/cell by setting `height:0` and `overflow:hidden` on all the elements, including a .box inside the cell, and it really doesn't work.

Please especially test on Safari, because it has some more problems than Firefox and Chrome.

Any way to get rid of the height and hide contents?

---

EDIT 1: for now, I've found out that IF using a **real html table** and adding `table-layout:fixed` to it **along with setting some width for it**, as for the official specs (and some other posts here in SO) the overflow property **does work**.

Though, it seems it doesn't work/apply to, css-tables, and I need css-tables.

---

EDIT 2: Thanks to @zer00ne I updated the fiddle and found that it --would-- work by setting font-size:0 both to td and input field. Though, it's not what I'm currently looking for, since I have to animate the field position and must be fully functional itself. Anyway, these 2 edits can be helpful for other people.

Comment: How are you animating the cell? CSS, JS, jQ, or plugin?

Comment: Yes, css animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about one week of searching for a solution, the answer is:

**no, it's still not possible**. At least, it's not possible in a reliable and versatile way. It's only possible in ways that somewhat limit elements or  future actions.

If one doesn't strictly need css-tables (like me in this specific case), you can successfully mimic the same behaviour in 2 ways:

- use real tables, apply `table-layout:fixed` and a width to the table (doesn't matter the unit, can be percentage, for ex.). Than just `height:0/oveflow:hidden` as usual.
- use flexbox. It's the css construct that, with the right rules applied, can better approximate the table behaviour.

Hope it helps

Comment: HTML tables are so strict... it's a pity so many libraries still use them... Thanks for doing the research, and informing us all that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set height of a row. Just place `div` tag inside each `td` and put your content in `div` but not in `td` directly. The height of row will be equal to height of its content. Set height and overflow for `div` element and set 0 in top and bottom padding of `td`. And of course you can use transition for height of `div`.

```js
$(function() {
 $('button').on('click', toggleColumn);
});

function toggleColumn() {
 $('div').toggleClass('rollup');
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 2s all;
}

div.rollup {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>toggle</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>Column 1</div></td>
    <td><div>Column 2</div></td>
    <td><div>Column 3</div></td>
    <td><div>Column 4</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply out after making the first row "invisible", you should simply be able to use CSS's :first-of-type like such:

```
/* Hide the first occurance of the 'tr' class */
.tr:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

Other than that, I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to do something like this, alternatively? (a bit like the method you had attempted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="tr hidden">
  <div class="td">
   My Content      
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

Last but not least, may I ask why you are creating a "handmade" table using div's, instead of [HTML's designated table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)?

Comment: As for the question title, I need height 0 and overflow hidden.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but why though? What kind of application requires height: 0; and overflow: hidden; in regards to just hiding it? @Stratboy

Comment: I need to hide the content of the row for animation purposes. It wouldn't be an issue if I could use a simple block element, but in this case I must use a css-table. Sadly, within a native table --should-- not be possible to really set the height of a row or cell if below a certain minimum, except using the fixed table-layout css prop, but in this case this way is not working too.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I've poked around in JSFiddle a little bit but unfortunately not found anything yet, and I'm afraid I can't do much more myself either. Best of luck though! @Stratboy

Comment: This also allows to create temporary fake hidden content that will help the table size each of its columns width with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate opening a table row with HTML tables using this css:

```
tr.info td {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
tr.info.hide td {
    line-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Remove the vertical padding which causes the apparent "minimum height" (thanks Andrey Shaforostov). Set opacity 0 to make the text appear as the row grows - smoother effect than using font-size. No need for inner div's - just add/remove the "hide" class on the table row.